# NotImplementedError: Operation of type AssignVariableOp (AssignVariableOp) is not supported on the TPU for inference

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to export SavedModel of a classifier of the type TPUEstimator. Since I'm trying to export the model to run predictions on a GPU/CPU, the use_tpu parameter of TPUEstimator was set to False.

When I try to save the model, the following error is thrown:

```
NotImplementedError: Operation of type AssignVariableOp
(AssignVariableOp) is not supported on the TPU for inference. Execution 
will fail if this op is used in the graph. Make sure your variables are 
using variable_scope.
```

Since I plan to serve the model through a GPU/CPU, the Op shouldn't be a problem. How can I export this estimator as SavedModel?

Answer (score 4):

This might help, just before calling export_savedmodel(...) call

**estimator._export_to_tpu = False**

Answer (score 1):

If you actually don't need TPU inference support you can create a tf.estimator.Estimator instead of a tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator one, using the same model_fn and trained model. Then, you should be able to export the model.